# cannot read property of undefined in postman while trying to post a new row in to my database

Tags: node.js, express, postman, rest

Im trying to make a rest API using POSTGRESQL and NODE js here . With the code below im able to get the data inside Postman but when i try to post a new row in to my database from Postman it shows the error "Cannot read property of undefined".ive spend 4 to 5 hours with this . need help

This is my code and my table name is users:

```
const client = require('./database.js')
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.listen(3300,()=>{
    console.log("Server is now listening at port 3300");
})
client.connect();

app.get('/users',(req,res)=>{
    client.query(`Select * from users`,(err,result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send(result.rows);
        }
    });
    client.end;
})

app.get('/users/:id', (req, res)=>{
    client.query(`Select * from users where id=${req.params.id}`, (err, result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send(result.rows);
        }
    });
    client.end;
})

app.post('/users', (req, res)=> {
    const user=req.body;
    console.log(user)
    let insertQuery = `insert into users(name, email, price, id) 
                       values(${user.name}, '${user.email}', '${user.price}', '${user.id}')`

    client.query(insertQuery, (err, result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send('Insertion was successful')
        }
        else{ console.log(err.message) }
    })
    client.end;
})
```

Comment: Please post the full error stack as you see it in terminal. It most probably mentions a line number where the error is. Guessing from your code it could onlz be that the user is undefined. PS: in Node.js you usually don't end the db connection after a request but rather keep it open as long as the app is running and reuse the connection.

Comment: what exactly does `console.log(user)` print?

Comment: It returns nothing . looks like im not getting it here.

Comment: // parse requests of content-type - application
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));
// parse requests of content-type 
app.use(express.json({ limit: "4096mb", extended: true }));

Comment: adding this both solved it for me .